# Split and/or partitioning large CNF file / Matrix

Tags: python, python-2.7, matrix, cnf, sat-solvers

simple issue. I have a very large CNF file with represents an m x n Matrix. lets say >10000 variables with related terms. So as a first step I want to partitioning the CNF file or even better split the matrix to variables of 100 for parallel solving concepts. Is there any description what rules to apply ?

All help is appreciated.

regards
Adrian

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [graph partitioning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_partition) tool like [Metis](http://glaros.dtc.umn.edu/gkhome/metis/metis/overview) to cluster the `CNF` clauses into independent sets which don't share any variables.

If it is not possible to identify truly disconnected clusters, the number of "link variables" might be small enough to enumerate their values. Such an enumeration basically assigns a tentative value to the connecting variables and eliminates them for the search process. The price to pay is that you have to run the search for every value combination.

Modern SAT solvers like [Cryptominisat](http://www.msoos.org/cryptominisat2/), [Riss3g](http://tools.computational-logic.org/content/riss3g.php) or [Lingeling](http://fmv.jku.at/lingeling/) apply various preprocessing measures to bring down the size of the problem. However, 10000 variables might be a feasible size to be solved without extra steps.

The CNF size alone is no reliable indicator or the problem complexity. [Tseitin encoding](http://verify.rwth-aachen.de/seminar/SAT09/propositional-sat.pdf) is a technique frequently used to reduce the number of clauses in CNF.

As recommended in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15995807/boolean-formula-encoding): A nice paper that contains a lot of useful references to work regarding SAT encoding is "Successful SAT Encoding Techniques" by Magnus Björk, 25th July 2009:
http://jsat.ewi.tudelft.nl/addendum/Bjork_encoding.pdf‎

Comment: Thanks a lot, will go though it